# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.captureStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas, capturestream

new to react, here i am getting live rtsp stream to canvas, i want to captureStream from it and change it to video tag, but for some reason when consoling captureStream i'm getting error: Uncaught TypeError: canvas.captureStream is not a function. I found some answers from stackoverflow but those had it working with one browser and not other, but in my case i am getting that error in every browser (chrome, firefox,safari ), any idea ?

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { loadPlayer } from 'rtsp-relay/browser';

const StreamVideo = () => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvas.current) throw new Error('Ref is null');

    loadPlayer({
      url: 'ws://.../api/stream',
      canvas: canvas.current,
    });
  }, []);
  var stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
  console.log('canvas element', stream);

  return (
    <div >
      <canvas ref={canvas} />
      <video />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StreamVideo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ref starts out `null`, so you can't call any methods on it until it has a value. And you must access the `current` property to get the canvas out of your ref.

You handle this in the effect, but not in your code below the effect.

You also need to type your ref properly so typescript knows what element it's going to have in it.

```
const canvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
```

In this case you can probably get away with calling `captureStream` with the `?.` operator so it it will only be called if `canvas` exists.

```
var stream = canvas.current?.captureStream(25);
console.log('canvas element', stream);
```

---

Here's [an example of a canvas streaming to a video tag](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-brook-jt1vu2?file=/src/App.tsx:339-381).

You have to set the `srcObject` property of a video tag reference to the created stream. You also need the `autoPlay` attribute set so the video plays it's stream.

Comment: this is working because my question contains directing stream from canvas to video tag, could you add that also ?

Comment: @walee I'm not sure what you mean. This addresses the `canvas.captureStream is not a function` error. I don't really know much about video streaming sadly, but I wanted to provide an answer to solves that error message.

Comment: i am using at the moment '      <canvas ref={canvas} />
' but i want to use <video  ref={canvas} /> instead, any idea how ?

Comment: Passing a canvas ref to a `<video>` tag doesn't really make much sense, but you can get a ref to the video tag just like you can get a ref to the canvas tag. Then you can call whatever APIs you want on those. First `const video = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)` then `<video ref={video} />`

Comment: live stream plays at the moment in my canvas but i want that to play in video tag instead, maybe i should not use ref in video tag ? can you suggest a way doing that ?

Comment: You need a ref to both. I've updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: i am doing exactly like you but my video tag is just black with same height and width as canvas stream

Comment: import { loadPlayer } from 'rtsp-relay/browser';
const StreamVideo = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
  if (!canvasRef.current) throw new Error('Ref is null');
  loadPlayer({
  url: 'ws://./api/stream',
  canvas: canvasRef.current,
  });
  if (canvasRef.current && videoRef.current) {
  const stream = canvasRef.current.captureStream();
  videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  }
}, []);
return (
<div style={{ border: '5px solid red' }}>
<canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
<video ref={videoRef} autoPlay /></div>);};
export...